# Confound - to make worse?

Tags: word-usage, dictionaries

[An American Heritage Dictionary definition I found in The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/confound) says about 'to confound':

> **3**. To make (something bad) worse: *Do not confound the problem by losing your temper.*

Some native speakers have told me they don't agree with this definition, and I haven't been able to find it in any major dictionaries except the American Heritage Dictionary.  Is the definition wrong?

Comment: **Who** doesn't agree with this definition? **Why**? What are their arguments? Why do **you** think it's wrong?

Comment: Native speakers don't agree. Why? Because they say it doesn't mean what the dictionary says. I don't think that it's either wrong or correct. I am not a native speaker as you are.

Comment: "Native speakers where? You heard wrong. Sorry. – Lambie" Are you saying that the dictionary correct?

Comment: There are a lot of uneducated native speakers with limited vocabularies. Why do you think some random native speaker from some random part of the world is more credible than a dictionary? [Wiktionary has a similar definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confound)

Comment: ColleenV, because this meaning is given only in one dictionary, Wiktionary excluded. Widktionary is not really a dictionary.

Comment: Then your question should mention that, not ask "native speakers" to proofread a dictionary entry. Native speakers are no more qualified to answer this question than any other person fluent in English.

Comment: I was asking for the opinions of native speaker on the issue, I never asked to proofread the dictionary entry.

Comment: "native speakers don't agree" is not a very useful answer to the inquiry "**who** doesn't agree".   There are about 400 million native speakers and I'm fairly sure you haven't consulted them all!.  If you said  "user3456" disagrees in this web post https:....  Then we could see.  If you said "my wife, who is a native speaker disagrees because ...." then we have something to answer.  Or my teacher,  or any specific person.  But not "native speakers"

Comment: @user1425 I realise that you feel annoyed, but please remain calm and be measured in your responses - I know from experience on this site that James K is a serious contributor and isn't trying to antagonise you.

Answer (score 5):

This usage of "confound" appears to be a [malapropism](https://www.lexico.com/definition/malapropism).  Lexico defines a malapropism as "The mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one, often with an amusing effect (e.g. ‘dance a *flamingo*’ instead of *flamenco*)".

Similarly, what we see in this definition is the mistaken use of "confound" where "compound" would be the correct verb.  To [compound](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compound) a problem is to make it worse.

Now, if this mistaken usage becomes sufficiently widespread then it will eventually become accepted usage (initially colloquially and then possibly more widely), but until then, learners (and others) would be best advised to use the correct word.

"Confound" meaning "make worse" doesn't appear in the mainstream dictionaries that I checked, although it has been pointed out that the definition quoted in the question is from the American Heritage Dictionary, usually considered a reputable source. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confound) offers "to increase the confusion of" as one of its definitions, which comes somewhat close but this isn't really the same thing as a general meaning of "to make worse".

NGrams shows that "confound the problem" is much, much [rarer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confound%20the%20problem%2Ccompound%20the%20problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#) in print compared with "compound the problem" (and some examples of the former are false positives, since they carry a different meaning, such as "confuse the problem [with another issue]").

Dictionaries checked: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/confound), [Chambers](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=confound&title=21st), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/confound), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confound), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/confound_1), [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/confound), [OED (requires subscription)](https://oed.com/view/Entry/38962?redirectedFrom=confound).  The contrary example: [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=confound).

Comment: It's possible that AHD is just admitting defeat and including the malapropism based on increased usage. I have a feeling that "confound" will be like "irregardless", although I would like to see a note by the definiton that it's nonstandard.

Comment: @ColleenV If so, there's a certain irony in that, because historically AHD was founded to provide a more prescriptive alternative to the perceived excessive permissiveness of M-W.

Comment: Times change. It looks like now they are "storytellers" and "story-changers" who value Trust, Justice, Learning, Innovation, Courage, and Ownership (https://www.hmhco.com/about-us). Nothing in there about "Truth" or "Correctness" :)

Comment: It looks like the AHD error has contaminated Wiktionary, and YourDictionary.com. While I was poking around OneLook dictionary search, I did come across [Websters 1828 dictionary's entry](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/confound) which does not have the "to make worse" entry. Maybe someone at AHD made a typo when entering definitions in their database.

Answer (score 0):

[American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=%20CONFOUND#:%7E:text=To%20make%20(something%20bad)%20worse,invention%20that%20confounded%20the%20skeptics.)

> tr.v. con·found·ed, con·found·ing, con·founds
>
> 1. To cause to become confused or perplexed. See Synonyms at perplex.
> 2. To fail to distinguish; mix up: Don't confound fiction and fact.
> 3. To make (something bad) worse: **Do not confound the problem by losing your temper.**
> 4. To cause to be ashamed; abash: an invention that confounded the skeptics.
> 5. Used in mild curses: Confound you!
> 6. a. To frustrate or thwart: trivial demands that confounded the peace talks. b. Archaic To defeat or overthrow (an enemy).

> [Middle English confounden, from Anglo-Norman confundre, from Latin
> cōnfundere, to mix together, confuse : com-, com- + fundere, to pour;
> see gheu- in the Appendix of Indo-European roots.]

In fact, **if you want another way to say**: Don't **make the problem worse**.
You would say:
Don't **confound** the problem, as given in 3. above.

Very simple.

compound the problem= to make the problem worse

> [ludwig guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/compound+the+problem)

- To compound the problem, Christians find it easier to emigrate. *The Economist*
- According to the research, some teachers are unsympathetic and teaching methods may compound the problem. **The Guardian**
- Keeping WorldCom on life support now would compound the problem. *New York Times*

to confound the problem = make it more confusing or worse
[ludwig guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/confound+the+problem)

To confound the problem, not every gene is disease-causing when mutated and the exact character of a disease gene is still unclear. *British Medical Genomics*

Confounding the problem, however, was the increase in the urban population, estimated at more than two-fifths during the same period. *Encyclopedia Britannica*

All of these noise sources confound the problem of separating meaningful signal from background signal. *Cellular and Molecular Bioengineering*

When compound and confound mean to make something worse or more confusing, they appear pretty much interchangeable.

However, we say: I was confounded [confused] by the problem and **we don't say**: I was compounded [buzzer]  by the problem. We do say: I compounded the problem by insisting I was fine.

Comment: I apologize, but what question did you answer? You just brought up the original source of confusion without really clearly stating your position on the matter. If it's OK to use "confound" to mean "make worse", why is it the only dictionary which mentions this?

Comment: Wait a second. I never doubted what you posted. I was asking whether you PERSONALLY agree with the dictionary and incidentally whether you use this word with the meaning in question in your life or do you hear other people use it that way? Dictionaries may have a lot of stuff which is not spoken in reality. I think you didn't understand my predominant concern.

Comment: For what it's worth, the full OED doesn't include any definition of "confound" comparable to the AHD's sense 3.

Comment: You might want to check all these out: The NYT, The Guardian and The Economist: https://ludwig.guru/s/compound+the+problem/ find these endless battles really boring.